# How to see process.env after starting server

Tags: node.js, npm

I am developing sample apps and would like to know process.env variables,
I know `console.log(process.env)` will return its variables.
But can I see them after run its server ?

`npm start`

I couldn't input anything in console.
As I am new to node.js, will you please let me know.
by switing `NODE_ENV`, it seems that `development`,`staging`,`production` is switched.
So that I would like to comfirm them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you start your server in docker and don't pass custom variables to `process.env` in your app, you can see your env by docker command:

```
docker exec your_container env
```

Yet another way - create a specific route in your application that will be return you all data from `process.env`.

Something like this:

```
GET yourserver/api/system/env
```

But this way is not secured and you should think about protection of your system route.

**UPD**

Also you can call console.log(process.env) after server has been started.

```
await app.listen(3000);
console.log(process.env);
```